# Thread Safe for WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, thread-safety

I tried to search thread safe for IWebDriver in C# and found answer which using [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx). But when i run my test it always return more than IWebDriver i instance in my code, it happen after run new test, I also tried using ThreadLocal.Dispose() after IWebDriver.Quit() and i got exception `System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'The ThreadLocal object has been disposed.'`. Hope someone work with thread safe for WebDriver in C# give me advices in my case.

Below is my code for return IWebDriver:

```
public class DriverFactory
{
     IWebDriver webDriver;        
     ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> ThreadDriver;
    private DriverFactory ()
    {

        //Do not instance out side
    }
    public static DriverFactory instance = new DriverFactory();
    public static DriverFactory Instance ()
    {
        return instance;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is use for return WebDriver
    /// </summary>
    public IWebDriver WebDriver
    {
        get
        {
            if(ThreadDriver.Value==null)
            //if (webDriver == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("The driver instance was not initialized. You should first call the method startDriver.");
            }
            return ThreadDriver.Value;
            //return webDriver;
        }

        private set
        {
            webDriver = value;
        }
    }      
    public void StartDriver (DriverType driverType)
    {
        switch (driverType)
        {               
            case DriverType.Chrome:
                ThreadDriver = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>(() =>
                {
                    return new ChromeDriver(Utils.DriverHelper.DriverPath());  
                },true);                 

                break;               
            default:
                break;
        }           
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is use for close WebDriver
    /// </summary>
    public void CloseWebDriver ()
    {
        //WebDriver.Close();
        //WebDriver.Quit();
        //WebDriver = null;
        //ThreadDriver.Value.Close();
        ThreadDriver.Value.Quit();
        ThreadDriver.Values.Clear();     
    }            
}
```

Here is my code for running test, i got issue when run paralell for testParalell1 and testParalell2:

```
[TestFixture(DriverType.Chrome)]
[TestFixture(DriverType.Chrome)]
[TestFixture(DriverType.Chrome)]
[TestFixture(DriverType.Chrome)]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
class ChangeDateTime
{
    protected DriverType driverType;
    public ChangeDateTime (DriverType type)
    {
        this.driverType = type;
    }        

    [Test]
    public void testParalell1 ()
    {
        DriverFactory.StartDriver(driverType);
        IWebDriver driver = DriverFactory.WebDriver;
        driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);
        Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google");
        DriverFactory.CloseWebDriver();
    }

    [Test]
    public void testParalell2 ()
    {
        DriverFactory.StartDriver(driverType);
        IWebDriver driver = DriverFactory.WebDriver;
        driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);
        Assert.AreEqual(driver.Title, "Google");
        DriverFactory.CloseWebDriver();
    }      

}
```

Comment: Well it looks like Quit() calls dispose so thats why you got the `System.ObjectDisposedException` when you tried to call dispose after quit.

Comment: I have solved this issue with making thread safe for IWebDriver in C#

Comment: @minhhoand can you provide us the information how you solved this issue please?

Comment: Could you please reference to my source code https://github.com/minhhoangvn/AutomationFramework/tree/master/AutomationFramework/Base/Driver